# landscape alternate xml layout crashing app [android]

Tags: android

OK so I have a normal functional portrait app layout with Buttons, TextViews etc. Using the same name I created a new layout for when the screen orientation is landscape, with some extra objects as well.

All runs well until I try to set an onTouchListener on the objects which are only displayed in Landscape mode. The app just crashes without warning when I try launching it (no error report from compiler either)...which is strange. Is there anyway around this? I suspect I can only declare onTouch on these objects once in landscape mode, if so, how to do this please?

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't post any code as there is no specific error linked to this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someting like this:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        // Your code
    } else{
        // Its portrait so do nothing
    }
```